# Can constants (vertex or fragment) be reset / nullified in Context3D?

Tags: flash, null, constants, vertex-shader, stage3d

If I make multiple draw calls for various `Program3D` instances, is there a way that I can **reset** or **nullify** the constants if I'm no longer using them in the next following `Program3D` assignment?

Is it even necessary that I do something like this?

```
//Nullify 'vc0' in the vertex shader:
context3D.setProgramConstantsFromVector("vertex", 0, null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, constants are global state to the entire Context3D. Their content does not change if you change programs. The default value is (0,0,0,0), but if you do not use them in a program there is no reason to set them.